# Check version of RPM package available in upstream repo if I have a custom one installed

Tags: rhel, yum

I have a RHEL6.1 machine that's registered with Redhat. I needed to install a customized version of a package (in my case, qemu-kvm), which I installed via RPM.

I can see the version info for my customized package by doing: "rpm -qi" or "yum info". How can I see the version information for the (non-customized) version of the RPM that exists in the Redhat repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yum provides "*/typical_qemu-kvm-file"
```

Should do the job.

```
yum search qemu-kvm
```

Is propably not enough.

```
yumdownloader --url qemu-kvm
```

might be another solution (just output url, do not download).

The syntax of the above commands is propably not 100% ok - I currently have no RH6 at hand to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Add --showduplicates to the list or info command line, and yum will show all versions of packages (including duplicate versions). Eg.

```
yum --showduplicates list qemu-kvm
```

...you can also use "repoquery --plugins qemu-kvm", as that ignores the local rpmdb by default.